# Pagination and get parameters

Tags: django

**Django 1.11.4**

I have build a search form with method="get".
Search form has a lot of forms.
Then this input values are transmitted as get parameters in url.

The problem is how to get pagination. The database contains thousands of objects. Pagination is necessary.

This is what the documentation tells us:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view

It suggests like this:

```
<a href="?page={{ contacts.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
```

But this will ruin all the get parameters.

What I have managed to invent is:

```
<a href="{{ request.get_full_path }}&page={{ object_list.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
```

This works. But this is goofy. If one switches pages forward and backward, it produces urls ending like this:

```
page=2&page=3&page=2
```

I have had a look at how Google managed this problem. In the middle of the url they have start=30. And change this parameter: start=20, start=40. So, they switch.

Could you help me understand how preserve get parameters and switch pages in Django? In an elegant way, of course.

Comment: I have a template tag I reuse on Github for this purpose: https://gist.github.com/benbacardi/d6cd0fb8c85e1547c3c60f95f5b2d5e1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically, to preserve GET parameters you simply re-write them manually. There shouldn't be many cases where having to do this will matter.

```
&page={{page}}&total={{total}}
```

You can abstract this away into a template include or a custom template tag.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/

Additionally, you could create a string filter that takes URL params as a string as well as a dict of values you want to change. The filter could then parse the params string, update the value, then recombine the string back into URL params.

```
{{ request.get_full_path | update_param:'page=8' }}
```

Answer (score 15):

The generic solution is to define a "custom template tag" (a function) which keeps the complete URL but updates the GET parameters you pass to it.

After registration, you can use this function in your templates:

```
<a href="?{% query_transform page=contacts.previous_page_number %}">previous</a>
```

To define and register the custom template tag, include this code in a python file:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def query_transform(context, **kwargs):
    query = context['request'].GET.copy()
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        query[k] = v
    return query.urlencode()
```

*Thanks to [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57158/ben) for the query_transform code. This is an adapation for python 3 from [his code](https://gist.github.com/benbacardi/d6cd0fb8c85e1547c3c60f95f5b2d5e1).

**Why this method is better than reconstructing the URLs manually:**

If you later decide that you need additional parameters in your URLs: 1. you don't have to update all the links in your templates.  2. You don't need to pass all the params required for recostructing the URL to the templates.

Answer (score 1):

### Subclassing

I solved this problem by subclassing Django's Paginator class and adding the stuff I needed there.

You need to override the init method to allow yourself to pass the request and form objects from the view, so that you can retrieve the request.GET parameters and compare them to form.fields.  You want to only allow GET parameter names that are predefined in your form.  Otherwise you remove them.

Once you have subclassed the Pagination class, you can use it in your views.py files, passing the extra request and form parameters to it.  Then you can render your template as suggested in the Django documentation, but now you have access to the paginator.first_params, paginator.last_params, page.previous_params, and page.next_params variables that you can use.

### pagination.py

```
import urllib

from django.core.paginator import Paginator as DjangoPaginator, EmptyPage

class Paginator(DjangoPaginator):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        form = kwargs.pop('form', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.params = {key: value for key, value in request.GET.items() if key in form.fields.keys()}

        self.first_params = urllib.parse.urlencode({**self.params, 'page': 1})
        self.last_params = urllib.parse.urlencode({**self.params, 'page': self.num_pages})

    def get_page(self, *args, **kwargs):
        page = super().get_page(*args, **kwargs)
    
        try:
            page.previous_page_number = page.previous_page_number()
        except EmptyPage:
            page.previous_page_number = None
        
        try:
            page.next_page_number = page.next_page_number()
        except EmptyPage:
            page.next_page_number = None
        
        page.previous_params = urllib.parse.urlencode({**self.params, 'page': page.previous_page_number})
        page.next_params = urllib.parse.urlencode({**self.params, 'page': page.next_page_number})
    
        return page
```

### views.py

```
from .pagination import Paginator

paginator = Paginator(queryset, per_page, request=request, form=form)
page = paginator.get_page(page_number)
```

### pagination.html

```
{% if page %}
    <nav id="pagination">
        {% if page.has_previous %}
            <a href="?{{ paginator.first_params }}">&laquo; First</a>
            <a href="?{{ page.previous_params }}" rel="prev">Previous</a>
        {% endif %}
        <span class="current">
            Page {{ page.number }} of {{ page.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>
        {% if page.has_next %}
            <a href="?{{ page.next_params }}" rel="next">Next</a>
            <a href="?{{ paginator.last_params }}">Last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </nav>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and find easier. Many not be better approach though!

```py
        param = ""
        if search_programs:
            qs = qs.filter(title__icontains=search_programs)
            param = param + f"&search_programs={search_programs}"
        if level:
            qs = qs.filter(level__icontains=level)
            param = param + f"&level={level}"
        if category:
            qs = qs.filter(sector__icontains=category)
            param = param + f"&category={category}"
        paginator = Paginator(qs, 16)
        page_number = self.request.GET.get('page')
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
        context = {
            'page_obj': page_obj,
            "param": param
        }
        return render(self.request, self.template_name, context)
# in html
 <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}{{param}}" class="page-link">next</a>
```